# DOCUSIGN : How to Bypass the Access code validation page by passing the access code programatically

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement where i want to validate a template using Access Code, but i want to bypass the access code validation by passing the Access code programatically(similar to how we can bypass the Initiator landing page https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-help/Content/populate-custom-fields.htm#pnz1578456644088).

Comment: To confirm, you're talking about requiring a signer to provide an access code to access their envelope, but having your application pre-populate the access code so the signer never sees / enters it?

Comment: Yes, correct. We can bypass the Signer landing page by passing the Username and Email address in the field <RoleName>_UserName = Signer full name and <RoleName>_Email = Signer Email address. Similarly is there a way to prepopulate the Access code and bypass the access code validation page so that Signer is never required to enter the Access code manually.

Comment: @Drew -- I believe the OP is asking about a Powerform whose template has an unneeded access code

Answer (score 0):

There is a value you can enter to bypass the access code validation. If you append the parameter ActivateOnly=1 at the end of your Email PowerForm URL, the recipient will not have to enter an Access Code

A Sample PowerForm URL would look like this:

https://www.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=ad01e352-158a-4380-96c9-9cbc4366028t&ActivateOnly=1

It is explained in more detail here:
https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Email-PowerForms-How-to-remove-system-generated-Access-Code-requirement

The problem with this option is that it requires users to access the powerform from their email

Comment: What is the value? Please don’t rely primarily on a link to answer the core of the question. Links should be used to offer ancillary information or supporting material, but your answer should include everything needed to solve the problem.

Comment: As per my requirement, my application users are not accessing the powerform via email. They access via the application where i redirect to the Powerform url. Hence i dont think ActivateOnly=1 will work out. Is there any other way of passing the Access code to Docusign without having to enter manually.

Comment: With ActivateOnly=1 the users can still activate the powerfrom from your application. The difference is that this adds an extra step  after it is activated where the user must check their email

As an alternative you can configure a short access code that the users won't mind having to enter

Answer (score 0):

If you need the template to be both available to your internal sending users as well as your Powerform, then split them up.

1. Duplicate your template by using "Create a Copy" from the drop-down menu.  Rename the one being used by your PowerForm and unshare it with your users. Remove the Access Code requirement from the template role.
2. Edit the duplicate template.  Ensure this one is shared with your users.